# Cloud Inventory Software

Tags: vps, cloud-computing

I'm looking for a solution that I would be able to install on a VPS server that would connect to my other VPS servers via SSH (or through a daemon) to check configuration, run scripts, or shutdown/reboot servers (boot up would be nice, but that's rather infeasible without integrating with the cloud provider's own APIs.

Is there anything that fits into this category? These machines aren't local to one another, so their IPs are public. I've done some basic research, but haven't managed to find anything suitable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like what you are asking for is possible with Nagios & NRPE. This article has [a introduction to NRPE](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/using-nrpe-to-monitor-remote-services/) and here's another article that talks about [restarting services using NRPE](http://www.techadre.com/content/nagios-event-handler-restarting-service) - something that can be pretty easily extended to rebooting the monitored instance itself.

Since all your machines have public IPs, you can setup SSH tunnels on your Nagios-Master to the SNMP interface on your Nagios-slaves which takes care of the security aspect.